# What is the 'callback' parameter in this common version of the mongodb.MongoClient.connect script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**NodeJS version**: v10.16.0

**MongoDB version**: 3.3.0

I am comfortable using 4 different versions of `mongoDB` connect scripts.  However on more than one occasion I've come across a specific type of connect script that I don't understand.  Specifically I don't understand what the `callback` parameter is or how it is being used/called.

This is one version of this connect script that uses the `callback` parameter.  How is this being used?  Why is it necessary?

```
function startDb(callback) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            let db = database;
            console.log("Database connection ready");
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function is being passed as the argument of `startDb()`. You can pass a function reference as as argument since everything is an object.

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello')
}

function indirectFunction(callback) {
    callback() // this will call the sayHello() function because it was passed as the argument
}

indirectFunction(sayHello) // logs 'Hello'
```

This is how it would be applied in the example you gave

```
function sayHello(response) {
    console.log(response) // will either log 'Hello' or the value of err
}

function startDb(callback) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            let db = database;
            console.log("Database connection ready");
            callback('Hello');
        }
    });
}

startDb(sayHello)
```

Comment: Brilliant, now I get it!